# Image Not Aligning Center

Tags: wordpress

I can not seem to get the image to align on this page: https://www.thewellnessproject.net/how-you-eat-is-how-you-live-the-7-types-of-eaters/

The image is set to center via the Wordpress post. I also went in and added adding CSS to try and center it (including adding it to wp-block-image and aligncenter size-large); neither seemed to work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Elementor and it is overwriting the properties for the `aligncenter` class which is used to align the image. Try adding below to your [custom CSS](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/) in theme editor.

```
.wp-block-image .aligncenter {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```